# Why does x[function() {}] work?

Tags: javascript

Why does the following code work?

```
var x = []
x[function() {}] = "Hi"

/* prints "Hi" */
console.log(x[function() {}])
```

**Edit**

I know that everything get's converted to a string-property, but why can I add `x["function() {}"] = "Yo"` then and have both properties?

[image]

Comment: `console.log(x)` could explain why it works.

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect it to work?

Comment: anything between [ ] is evaluated and converted to string. and that converted string acts as the key of the object. so function() {} is converted to "function () {}". Later u access that key from the object.

Comment: "*why can I add `x["function() {}"] = "Yo"` then and have both properties?*" - you cannot. It's the same property.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, apparently the function is serialised with a space between the `function` keyword and the parameter list, so it's two different strings.

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my understanding, when you put anything in `[]`, that value is converted to string.

So when you do `[function(){}]`, it means `["function(){}"]` which is a valid value.

If you try something like this, it would be more evident:

```js
var foo = {};
var bar = {};

var a = [];
a[foo] = "hello";
a[bar] = "world";

console.log(a[foo], a[bar], Object.keys(a))
```

Comment: 7 upvotes in a minute! That's got to be some kind of record.

Comment: @cst1992 What do you expect on questions like this?

Comment: @FabianZeindl In the image that you have shared, if you notice, there is a **space** between `function` and `()`. This makes it different string values.

Comment: Facepalm. Thank you :)

Comment: @Downvoter Please comment

Answer (score 1):

The property names of objects (including arrays) are always strings in JavaScript. 
If the value passed to indexer is not a string, it's coerced to such. 
`(function (){}).toString() === (function() {}).toString()`